# Field expression GroupBy not returning included objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

In this code:

```
var dbrepayments = _context.Repayments.Include("Loan").Include("Loan.Borrower").Include("Loan.LoanProduct")
                           .Where(c => c.PaidOn == null && c.DateOfRepayment <= today)
                           .GroupBy(c => c.Loan.Id, (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault())
                           .OrderBy(c => c.DateOfRepayment);
```

`_context` is `ApplicationDbContext` type that I am using to get results from database using Code-First approach.

The problem is when I try to iterate through `dbrepayments` and get the value of `Loan`, `Loan.Borrower`, and `Loan.LoanProduct` objects they are showing as `null`. But when I remove `GroupBy`, these objects are returned correctly.

Comment: Can you show the iterating code and how you are trying to get `Loan` etc

Comment: It sounds like `GroupBy` is evaluating locally and thus is projecting the database results to a new type which means you lose the included types. Check the console output for any LINQ translation warnings.

Comment: @Matt not any complex code. Even if I do like this `var x = dbrepayments.FirstOrDefault().Loan` it is returning `null`.

Comment: @KieranDevlin I don't see any warnings in Output window.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager the issue here is the element selector in your `GroupBy` statement:

```
(key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault()
```

This didn't make a lot of sense when I first read it. You are taking repayments grouped by loan, but then trying to select just the last repayment for each loan? Followed by ordering those first repayments by date.

I believe this will give you the results you're looking for with the eager loaded relationships:

```
var dbrepayments = _context.Repayments.Include("Loan").Include("Loan.Borrower").Include("Loan.LoanProduct")
                           .Where(c => c.PaidOn == null && c.DateOfRepayment <= today)
                           .GroupBy(c => c.Loan.Id)
                           .Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault())
                           .OrderBy(c => c.DateOfRepayment);
```

`GroupBy` will respect `Include` but if you are using a select expression, that overrides it. You cannot add `Include` inside the selector as that is working with IEnumerable of the expected results. Instead, group the results by loan as expected, but then `Select` from the results to get the latest repayment. This will give you a list of the latest repayments that you can then order.